# How to play video files with .DM extension?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I had some files I transferred from my computer to my iPhone via Zapya and deleted actual files later on

I wanted to recover later and discovered that actual files are nowhere but I can see same files with same size but with .DM extension in my `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Zapya\Video` folder

I tried removing `.DM` extension and played on MPC-HC player and also on VLC Player but it does not play

Any idea on how to recover those files?

Answer (score 1):

A file with the .DM extension is a file (often audio) that has been encoded with DRM (Digital Rights Management) copy-protection; used by some cell phones for ringtones and other media clips, but can also be used for digitally signed mobile applications; can only be opened using an authorized cell phone.

Since these files are protected with DRM (Digital Rights Management) copy-protection software, a cell phone must be authorized in order to use them.

Comment: Do you have any clue how to unlock it? I have that iPhone which I used to transfer that file with

Comment: Only the phone that is authorized to use the file will be able to play the file; you'll only be able to play the videos on your iPhone.

Comment: i tranfered those files to my phone but they dont play

Comment: Where did the media files originally come from?

Comment: it was recorded in iPhone .. I moved that from iphone to my computer using zapya,